# Using exclusive-or in sbcl type declarations

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

For a function like:

```
(defun test (x y)
   (declare (optimize (speed  3)))
   (< x y))
```

I see a warning containing this:

```
note: 
unable to
  open-code FLOAT to RATIONAL comparison
due to type uncertainty:
  The first argument is a REAL, not a FLOAT.
  The second argument is a REAL, not a RATIONAL.
```

If I know that either both arguments  are going to be RATIONAL xor FLOAT, is there a declaration hint I can give to sbcl for this?

Answer (score 5):

You can't declare that kind of relationships among types, but what you could do is define some auxiliary functions, where the type is asserted but not checked:

```
(macrolet ((defexpansion (name type)
             `(progn
                (declaim (inline ,name))
                (defun ,name (x y)
                  (declare (type ,type x y)
                           (optimize (safety 1)
                                     (speed 3)))
                  (< x y)))))
  (defexpansion test-fixnum fixnum)
  (defexpansion test-float float)
  (defexpansion test-rational rational))
```

Then, you only need to typecheck the first argument, since you *know* that the second one is necessarily of the same type (this is what the declaration says, and you asked the compiler to trust you).

```
(defun test (x y)
  (etypecase x
    (float (test-float x y))
    (fixnum (test-fixnum x y))
    (rational (test-rational x y))))
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `test-rational` in the third case?

Answer (score 4):

You can give `sbcl` some information about the type of your data:

```
(defun test (x y)
  (declare (optimize (speed  3))
           (type rational x y))
  (< x y))
```

You should decide whether you can tell the type of `x` and `y` in all circumstances or not.

You can find more information about type declaration in the [hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_type.htm) and sbcl's [manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/).

**EDIT**

I don't know if it makes sense at all but one could think about another layer which decides which function is called:

```
(defun test% (x y)
  (declare (optimize (speed  3)))
  (if (and (typep x 'rational) (typep y 'rational))
      (test-rational x y)
      (test-float x y)))

(defun test-rational (x y)
  (declare (optimize (speed  3))
           (type rational x y))
  (< x y))

(defun test-float (x y)
  (declare (optimize (speed  3))
           (type float x y))
  (< x y))
```

I guess there is room for further optimization using `typecase` or defining methods for each type using `CLOS`.

Comment: Hi Martin,
I was unclear. I understand that this is the type hint I can add when I *know* that both x and y are rational, but in this case I know that they are either both rational or both float, and giving this type hint will cause a performance dip if the inputs are floats.

Comment: Hmm, now I get it. But I have no clue if first checking the type and then declaring it for the following operations is possible and makes sense at all from a perfomance perspective.